# Spark Optimization

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I am reading a Hive table and doing a simple `sum(field1)` for one of the fields on the table and then performing a show function by doing `.show()`

The table has nearly 12million rows and it is taking 18secs to run the job on YARN. The same function takes less than 10secs on SQL Server.

Thoughts on how to optimize the query on Spark?

Comment: Did you submit the spark application to a YARN cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If you could have posted the query that would have been better.Anyways there are some generic options which you can use to optimize a spark job:

1.Set shuffle partitions before any df is executed as below

```
sql("""SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=400""")
```

2.Use of Broadcast join which will parallelize the execution.(in case if you are using joins)

```
select  /*+ BROADCAST (B) */ a.colum1 FROM   completedata  INNER JOIN (select column 2 from completedata2) B
```

3.Tweaking the executers and executor memory.
Hope this helps!